# My php string turns out strange when encoded to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using wordpress inside my own made theme. This code i linked is inside a page template i custom made.

It's very easy.  I am trying to convert a php array to a javascript array. I have this php script:

```
$userArray = array('John Doe', 'john@example.com');
```

And this javascript:

```
 var users = '<?php echo json_encode($userArray); ?>';
 jQuery(this).val(users[0]);
 // this displays my value inside a textfield.
```

The strange thing is:

```
users[0] displays this: [
users[1] displays this: "
users[2] displays this: J
users[3] displays this: o
```

So together i looks like it spells ["John doe"].
users[0] should be "john doe"

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening? 
Thanks in advance for the help and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `users` variable contains a string, and if you try accessing a string as an array in Javascript, you will get the character in the `index` position, which is why your getting that result (see "Character access" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)).

Apart from `JSON.parse`ing it, you can leave the quotes out and it will be interpreted as JSON:

```
<?php
    $userArray = array('John Doe', 'john@example.com');
?>
<script>
    var users = <?php echo json_encode($userArray); ?>;
    console.log(users[0]); // John Doe
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `JSON.parse` the string first. Variable `users` is a string and needs to be converted to array or object .

```
var users = '<?php echo json_encode($userArray); ?>';
users = JSON.parse(users); /* Parse the string to array or object */
jQuery(this).val(users[0]);
```

Or you can make the code shorter by:

```
var users = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($userArray); ?>');
jQuery(this).val(users[0]);
```